# Python Code for Home Automation times out

Tags: python, networking, home-automation

I was making a python script for home automation using Adafruit IO as a conduit between IFTTT and the Raspi, and it works great for a while. But after a few hours, it just stops working. I have no monitor connected, as the raspi is mounted to my wall. Below is my code:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from Adafruit_IO import *
from Adafruit_IO import MQTTClient

clear = "CLEAR"

ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = "ADAFRUIT IO USERNAME"
ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = "ADAFRUIT IO KEY"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)

def connected(client):
    client.subscribe('welcome-feed') #may need to change this feedname later
    print "Connected!"
    client.publish('welcome-feed', clear)
    client.publish('welcome-feed', clear)   
    time.sleep(1.5)

def disconnected(client):
    print 'Lost connection to server!'
def message(client, feed_id, payload):
    if payload == "LIGHT" :
        print "LIGHT command received from IFTTT."
        print "LIGHTS TOGGLED!"
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
    elif payload == "FAN_LOW" :
        print "FAN SPEED SET TO LOW!"
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)

    elif payload == "FAN_MED" :
        print "FAN SPEED SET TO MEDIUM!"
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
    elif payload == "FAN_HIGH" :
        print "FAN SPEED SET TO HIGH!"
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)

    elif payload == "FAN_OFF" :
        print "FAN IS OFF"
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print"Message from IFTTT received: %s" % payload

client = MQTTClient (ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)

# Setup the callback functions defined above.
# English: If it connects, go to connected, if it gets a msg go to message

client.on_connect   = connected
client.on_message   = message
client.on_disconnect    = disconnected

print 'Attempting a connection to the server...'
client.connect()
client.loop_background() # loop in background


while 1 == 1:
    time.sleep(120)
    client.publish('welcome-feed', "PING")
```

Any ideas as to why it isn't working? I thought it might be a connection to the server timing out because of inactivity, so I set up a part of the code to post "PING" to the server every 2 minutes, but that didn't help. Thanks for your help!!!  :D  :D

Comment: Why do you call `client.publish('welcome-feed', clear)` twice?

Comment: Not a good idea to publish your `ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME`  and `ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY`. You should edit/scrub them...

Comment: Kennet Runner, thank you for pointing that out! I can't beleive I forgot to delete that... hopefully everybody who saw it will do the right thing and, well, you know, not spam the hell out of my welcome feed...

Comment: Dmitry Grigoryev, I called it twice because for some reason if I don't, it will see the last called command and perform it. Its a remnant of v1 of my code before I started pinging ever 2 minutes, I just never removed it.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of [this **open**](https://github.com/adafruit/io-client-python/issues/20) github issue and this [one that is closed but not yet merged](https://github.com/adafruit/io-client-python/issues/11) the client disconnect functionality is not 100% yet.

Also, there's no error handling in your code, and even if you did get disconnected cleanly then your *ping* loop will continue trying to publish.
Have a look at the e[xceptions types here](https://github.com/adafruit/io-client-python/blob/master/Adafruit_IO/errors.py) and implement some error handling.

I would look at forgetting the `client.loop_background()` call and instead go for a forever loop like this

```
while 1 == 1:
    if client.connected() :
        # yay, we're still connected, so see if there are any messages
        client.loop(5)   # 5 second timeout waiting for a message
    else
        # we got disconnected somehow, so reconnect
        client.connect()
```

Comment: `while True` looks better than `while 1 == 1` to me...